# Show UIPicker when my UITextField is selected

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uipickerview, ios8

I am trying to show a UIPicker that it is initially hidden whenever I touch/select/press my UITextField.

Here is my code so far:

```
class RegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var getGender: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()

    @IBOutlet var genderTextField: UITextField! = nil

    @IBOutlet var passTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var repassTextField: UITextField!



    let gender = ["Male", "Female", "Other"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        genderTextField.delegate = self

        passTextField.secureTextEntry = true
        repassTextField.secureTextEntry = true

        getGender.hidden = true


        if(genderTextField.becomeFirstResponder()){

        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // returns the number of 'columns' to display.
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    // returns the # of rows in each component..
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return gender.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return gender[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        genderTextField.text = "\(gender[row])"

    }
```

I have everything set up so the genderTextField changes its value whenever you select the values from the getGender UIPicker. However, I did not success with trying to make the pickerView show up whenever I click the genderTextField.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are planning on using more than one `UIPickerView` on the controller, you don't need to `setGender.hidden = true`  and then `setGender.hidden = false` at all.  Note that this doesn't hide collapse the picker view, it just hides view so that you are left with a blank box where the picker view or keyboard would have been.

You can add `self.view.endEditing(true)` to your `didSelectRow` message as follows

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    genderTextField.text = "\(gender[row])"
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you set up your getGender `UIPickerView`, but it looks like you just set `getGender.hidden = true` on viewDidLoad.

To make this appear again, hook up your [UITextField Delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and set `getGender.hidden` to `false` in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost fine just a small fix required. You are not setting up default input method for text field.

First of all probably you don't need `IBOutlet` on your picker view since you don't want it all the time to be visible in your view and UI builder but instead just pop it up a single time when text box is clicked. So it is safe to remove it.

Secondly you need to change default input to `UIPickerView` and delegate it to `self`

```
getGender.delegate = self
genderTextField.inputAccessoryView = getGender
```

Should work, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I had been having a similar issue. It may not be the cleanest way, but I found making use of both `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing` can unhide and dismiss the pickerView:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == genderTextField {
        getGender.hidden = false
    }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == genderTextField {
        resignFirstResponder()
        getGender.hidden = true
    }
}
```

I am sure there is probably an easier way to achieve this, but hope it helps for now.

I've unfortunately found that the keyboard from the textField tends to hide my picker view when it's displayed at the bottom of the UI. I've had to change the input method of the UITextField to prevent this from happening (in viewDidLoad).

```
genderTextField.inputView = getGender
```

(if you experiences crashes with this, do not include getGender as a subView of your ViewController)

Hope this helps!